# Help with Texturing a tapered cylinder

Tags: texturing

I'm working on my exploded golf ball some more and want to add a similar golf ball dimple texture to a stand that is a tapered cylinder. This is my current workflow with the shader nodes similar to what I did with the head. Any tips here to keep the image from distorting? Is there a way to wrap this better than what I'm currently trying?

Thanks!
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dayw2xpze1rj5u2/Golf%20Ball%20Test.blend?dl=0

Side note: Apologies I'm still pretty new here, is there an easier way to share files here? I seem to remember people embedding blend files directly. Thanks

Comment: so you want those dots (dimples?) to be round and not oblong at the tapered part correct? can you share your file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie that's correct! It seems to wrap around the part vertically strange as well. I had also tried using the same bump map I used for the spherical ball but that was much worse so I instead created a simple repeating cylindrical pattern that you see here. I'll edit my post to include the blend file.

Comment: couldn't see the texture i think you forgot to do a *File > External Data > Pack Resources*. btw you have overlapping duplicate vertices. in edit mode select all vertices and press `M` *> Merge By Distance*. And i think you have to [add some seams](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/seams.html) so you can have the UV map in square grids.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie thanks. I packed the resources and edited my download file if you'd like to look again. Thanks for the tip on seams as well. I didn't do that so I'll take a look and see if that helps